# VB.NET WinForms: DrawString does not center, despite using Stringformat.Center

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drawstring

I'm trying to draw my text in the center of my (test) rectangle.

my (simplified) code:

```
Sub Main()

    Using x As New Form1()
        x.ShowDialog()
    End Using

End Sub

Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        Dim g As Drawing.Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics

        Dim rect As New Rectangle(3, 3, 15, 15)
        Dim sf As New StringFormat
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center

        g.DrawString("0", New Font("Verdana", 6.0!, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point, 0), New SolidBrush(Color.Black), rect, sf)
        g.DrawRectangle(New Pen(New SolidBrush(Color.HotPink), 1), rect)

    End Sub

End Class
```

which yields the following result

[image]

It looks 'ok', but it's not perfectly centered.

[image]

How can I align this perfectly centered?

I have tried different fonts and font sizes, but to no avail.

Comment: Text renderers fit glyphs to the pixel grid for optimum readability.  Being off by 1 pixel some times when the left-over white space is not divisible by 2 is thus inevitable.  A fixed-pitch font will be more predictable since the glyphs have a fixed width.

Comment: I've tried Courier and other monospaced fonts, but the result is the same. More often than not, the text is off by more than one pixel. No matter if the rectangle is 15 or 16 pixels in size.

Comment: If it's just a number between 0 and 9 you can adjust the x and y position of the string. In your g.DrawString(...) just replace the "rect" by the x and y directly. So where you have ...New SolidBrush(Color.Black), rect, sf), you can have it like: New SolidBrush(Color.Black), 6,6, sf)